# how to import in csv

Tags: django, csv, django-admin

I m having a porblem.I m exporting data to an excel in my django admin.The functionality is fine until some special characters are not there.

I have a text **"    ACTPrinter ★ Print to iPhone   "** when i try to export this to an csv file ,
it gives an error

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/core/wappubfilter/

'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2605' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

any idea how to solve it.I tried giving the tring under unicode but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should convert all the data into utf-8. this is done like this:

```
writer.writerow(
        [unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in data]
    )
```